# $A_n \uparrow A \implies 1_{A_n} \uparrow 1_A$ pointwise?

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $\Omega$ be the set.  Let $1_A$ be the characteristic function on a set, i.e. it has value $1$ iff $x \in A$ and $0$ otherwise.  Suppose There's a sequence of subsets $(A_n)_{n\geq 1}$ increasing to a subset $A$.  Then is this true: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1_{A_n}(w) = 1_A(w), \forall w\in\Omega$?

Comment: Obvious question.  It seems to be true.

Comment: If $(A_n)_n$ is increasing, then $\bigcup(A_n)_n=A$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}1_{A_n}(\omega)=1_A(\omega)\forall\omega\in\Omega.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Split to two cases, $w \in A$ and $w \notin A$. In each case, think in which (if any) of the subsets $A_n$ you can expect to find $w$.

Comment: For a second I was working on it and it seemed like it wasn't true.  And I needed it for a proof.